# Cycle pages in jekyll which onclick trigger

Tags: jekyll

I have created a directory ../category/{{page.title}} which make pages corresponding to individual category. I am trying to cycle those pages using a image on-click event. Something similar to carousal in bootstrap but in jekyll liquid only.
Here is the code

```
{% for item in site.categories %}
 <a href="item.url"> 
    <img src ="My image location"> 
 </a>
{% endfor %}
```

On click it redirects to my particular category post which is last in order.

Comment: You are aware that jQuery is JavaScript and runs client-side in the browser, while Liquid only runs once server-side to generate your *static* page? That said, I am not sure what your question really is.

Comment: Yep, what Polygnome said is correct. Can you rewrite your question so it's more explicit?